# Change the schema from elmah_error table in Postgres

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, elmah

I wanto to change the schema of the `elmah_error` table from public to elmah.

I'm getting this error: `Npgsql.NpgsqlException: relation "elmah_error" does not exist`. It keep's searching for this table on public only.

On the Web.config I'm trying to set `schema=elmah` on the errorLog with no success. Found some `Sqlerrolog.cs` to add the schema, but I'm using PgsqlErrorLog on errorLog and found no `PgsqlErrorLog.cs` to change.

Someone have a hint about what to do in this situation?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I am not as familiar with the asp.net or C# side, but on the PostgreSQL side there are three basic approaches.  The first is to qualify the table with a schema name, i.e.

```
select ... from elmah.elmah_error
```

Another option is to set search path for the session:

```
SET search_path = 'elmah';
```

A third option is to alter parameters so that the search path will automatically be set.

```
ALTER USER aspnet_user SET search_path = 'elmah';
```

You can alter users or databases to set the search path.